How to Detecting a manual reset of a fully managed enrolled device using the Android Management API?
How can I Detecting a manual reset of a fully managed device using the Android Management API?
** Device State in API Response**:

When I call the enterprises.devices.get API for the device, check the DeviceState field in the response. If it remains unchanged, it might indicate that the device is not reporting its state correctly.
If the state is still enrolled and not deleted, it means the device is still managed, but the manual reset might not have been detected yet.

How can I solve the issue?

Unfortunately, directly detecting a user-initiated factory reset on a fully managed device using the Android Management API is not currently supported. To determine stale devices, it is recommended to rely on  and call the enterprises.devices.delete method for cleanup.
